# Collect files from all subdirectories

Tags: terminal, subdirectory

I have a directory with about 5,000 subdirectories in it.

Each subdirectory contains one file each.

I'd like to collect those files and put them in the same folder somewhere.

Is there a way to do that by Mac OSX terminal command? Or should I write a, say, python script to do that?

Comment: It would be helpful to know which OS this is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like,

```
find . -type f -exec echo mv {} /path/to/dst/dir/ \;
```

You'll have to tweak this according to your circumstances, of course.  See `man find` for details.  Remove the `echo` when you're ready to run for real (preferably after taking a backup).

Comment: what should I do for "find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"" error?

Comment: Add the terminating ';' or '+'.

Comment: I would suggest counting the files before and afterwards, since the script will happily overwrite files where names clash - I mean if you have a/fred.txt and b/fred.txt, you will lose one of them.